# Getting the "Invalid module instantiation" in my FIR Verilog code

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

My code is a sequential structure, 8 constant taps, 8 bit FIR. I used a memory to save all the input*taps, but I keep getting and error while trying to save these multiplications.

I compiled it on Modelsim and got "syntax error". After, I tried iverilog and got "syntax error" and "error: Invalid module instantiation". I feel like I'm missing something really obvious but couldn't solve it.

The code goes as follows:

```
/*  Código de um filtro FIR 8 taps, 8 bits
Aluno: Rafael Menezes
Start date: 19/07/2017

Modelo original - Sequencial ALTERNATIVO por reg+load
v1.5

BUG REPORT: 
    - Problema com a memória das multiplicações (linha 54);

NOTES:
    - Incrementador do sel é feito por always (linha 59);
    - Necessita, também, fazer o xor pro load (?);
*/

//código do fir
module fir(x,clk,rst,y);
input signed [8:0]x;                        //entrada do fir
input clk,rst;                              //clock e reset
output signed [16:0]y;                      //saída do fir
reg signed [16:0] m[0:7];                   //variáveis auxiliares para as multiplicações
wire signed [8:0]x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7;      //variáveis auxiliares para os atrasos
wire signed [8:0]x_aux;                     //variável auxiliar para o atraso selecionado pelo mux
wire signed [8:0]h_aux;                     //variável auxiliar para o tap selecionado pelo mux
reg         [2:0]sel;                       //variável responsável pelo select do mux
parameter n=8;                              //parâmetro do loop das multiplicações

// valores pré-definidos dos taps
parameter signed h0=-4'd1;
parameter signed h1=4'd7;
parameter signed h2=-4'd2;
parameter signed h3=4'd5;
parameter signed h4=-4'd5;
parameter signed h5=4'd3;
parameter signed h6=4'd1;
parameter signed h7=4'd4;

    //atrasos
    ffd u1(clk,rst,x,x1);   //x[n-1]
    ffd u2(clk,rst,x1,x2);  //x[n-2]
    ffd u3(clk,rst,x2,x3);  //x[n-3]
    ffd u4(clk,rst,x3,x4);  //x[n-4]
    ffd u5(clk,rst,x4,x5);  //x[n-5]
    ffd u6(clk,rst,x5,x6);  //x[n-6]
    ffd u7(clk,rst,x6,x7);  //x[n-7]

genvar i;
generate
    for (i=0; i<n; i=i+1) begin: mux
    mux81 mux1(.clk(clk),.sel(sel),.in1(x),.in2(x1),.in3(x2),.in4(x3),
                    .in5(x4),.in6(x5),.in7(x6),.in8(x7),.out(x_aux));           //mux que seleciona as entradas
    mux81 mux2(.clk(clk),.sel(sel),.in1(h0),.in2(h1),.in3(h2),.in4(h3),
                    .in5(h4),.in6(h5),.in7(h6),.in8(h7),.out(h_aux));           //mux que seleiona os taps
    m[i]=x_aux*h_aux;       // THE ERROR IS RIGHT HERE!
    end
endgenerate

//rotina que incrementa o select a cada pulso de clock
always @(posedge clk) begin 
    if (sel==3'b111) begin
         sel <= 3'b000;
    end else begin
         sel <= sel + 3'b001;
    end
end

    assign y=m[0]+m[1]+m[2]+m[3]+m[4]+m[5]+m[6]+m[7];       

endmodule


//código do flip flop d que será usado como o integrador (atraso)
module ffd(clk,rst,in,out);
input clk,rst;
input signed [8:0]in;
output signed [8:0]out;
reg signed [8:0]out;

always @ (posedge clk) begin            //sembre na borda de subida verifica se o rst está ligado
    if(rst==1) begin                    //se não estiver ligado, atribui a entrada para a saída
        out<=0;
    end else begin
        out<=in;
    end
end

endmodule

//código mux para selecionar os taps e as entradas
module mux81(clk,sel,rst,in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7,in8,out);
input signed [8:0]in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7,in8;
input [2:0]sel;
input clk,rst;
output signed [8:0]out;
reg signed [8:0]out;

always @ (posedge clk or sel) begin
    if (rst==1) begin
        out<=0;
    end else if (sel==3'd0) begin
        out<=in1;
    end else if (sel==3'd1) begin
        out<=in2;
    end else if (sel==3'd2) begin
        out<=in3;
    end else if (sel==3'd3) begin
        out<=in4;
    end else if (sel==3'd4) begin
        out<=in5;
    end else if (sel==3'd5) begin
        out<=in6;
    end else if (sel==3'd6) begin
        out<=in7;
    end else if (sel==3'd7) begin
        out<=in8;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Please don't vandalise titles here with begging - it creates work for volunteer editors.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Well, it's my first post here so I wouldn't know, sorry. Thanks for the heads up, but downvoting my post won't help anyone. In fact, will do exact opposite. Cheers.

Comment: did you mean `always @*   m[i]=x_aux*h_aux;` ?

Comment: Thank you my good Sir! That did the work Serge. Thanks :D

Comment: Don't take downvotes personally - they are just messages here. I subscribe to the view that it is not reasonable to demand urgency from volunteers under any circumstances, on any website, or in any situation offline, and that one does not need guidelines in order to know this.

Comment: We do not add "solved" to post titles here either. Would you add the solution in an answer below? You can then "self-accept" by clicking the tick mark. (If you or @Serge can explain _why_ it solves the problem, that might be very useful for future readers!).

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it, just know that it was a syntax problem. I'm new to Verilog - this is my first project using the language -, so it'd be better if @Serge could explain.

Comment: I added an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Verilog module syntactically might contain declarations, procedural blocks, continuous asisgnments, and module instantiations. The expression like this `m[i]=x_aux*h_aux;` standing alone confuses the verilog compiler. The fact that it is used inside the 'generate' block does not change anything because the latter does not represent such a scope and only in-lines its ins internals.

So, I assume that OP wanted to assign a value to the register 'm[i]' (where [i] is a generated index). In verilog this can be done in an procedural block (always block in such a case). So, the correct use, taking in account verilog v2k syntax is:

```
always @* 
    m[i]=x_aux*h_aux;
```

in system verilog I recommend to use this instead:

```
always_comb
    m[i]=x_aux*h_aux;
```

Comment: @halfer yep, ... fixed.