# hex value in verilog generate for loop

Tags: for-loop, verilog, system-verilog

I have this code in systemverilog where i have to use hex numbers in for loop. I am trying below syntax and code.

```
genvar i,j;

localparam int i_d = 1;

localparam int j_d = 134;

generate

for (i = 8'h01; i <= MAX1; i = i + INCR)

begin

    add_bit[i_d] = (creg_add == i);

    i_d = i_d + 1;

end

for (j = 8'h86; j <= MAX2; j = j + INCR)

begin

    add_bit[j_d] = (creg_add == j);

    j_d = j_d + 1;

end

endgenerate
```

But i am facing this error. Can someone help me here?

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
 Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "creg.vs",
  715: token is '['
              add_bit[i_d] = (creg_add == i);
              ^
```

Comment: what is `add_bit`? you  probably need `assign ad_bit[i_d] = ....`. I think it is a duplicate for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491164/getting-the-invalid-module-instantiation-in-my-fir-verilog-code

Comment: what have you defined `add_bit` as?

Comment: add_bit is defined as logic

Answer (score 2):

`generate` blocks are evaluated at elaboration time (pre-simulation). You can have `always` blocks, `assign` statements, module instances, and local-scoped variable deescalation inside them. Directly assigning a value that will be continuously updated outside an `always` block or `assign` statement is not allowed.

`localparam`s are constants therefore the line `i_d = i_d + 1` is illegal.

A simpler solution would be to use procedural assignment in an combinational always block.

```
int i,j;
int i_d, j_d;
logic [WIDTH:0] add_bit;

always_comb begin
  i_d = 1;
  j_d = 134;
  add_bit = '0; // fill zeros in case of gap between last i_d and first j_d
  for (i = 8'h01; i <= MAX1; i = i + INCR)
  begin
    add_bit[i_d] = (creg_add == i);
    i_d = i_d + 1;
  end
  for (j = 8'h86; j <= MAX2; j = j + INCR)
  begin
    add_bit[j_d] = (creg_add == j);
    j_d = j_d + 1;
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for help; instead of using add_bit[i_d],  can i use add_bit[i]?   will that be able to understand hex values in index ?

Comment: The radix doesn't matter (hex, dec, bin, oct).  Use whichever radix is easier to work with. `134` and `8'h86` are equivalent and mostly interchangeable. I am guessing `INCR` is greater than 1 which would explain why `i` and `i_d` are not the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue.

```
genvar i,j;

localparam int i_d = 1;

localparam int j_d = 134;

generate

for (i = 8'h01; i <= MAX1; i = i + INCR)

begin

    assign add_bit[i_d] = (creg_add == i);

    i_d = i_d + 1;

end

for (j = 8'h86; j <= MAX2; j = j + INCR)

begin

    assign add_bit[j_d] = (creg_add == j);

    j_d = j_d + 1;

end

endgenerate
```

Comment: This will not compile because `i_d`/`j_d` are incremented. Adding `assign` will not work because they are localparams (aka constants).